# xml node values with their respective parent node in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlxml

```
<ExecutionSequence>
    <property name="Id">1437</property>
    <property name="Name">seq</property>
        <ExecutionBlock>
            <property name="Name">Block1</property>
            <ExecutionCommand>
                <property name="Name">Cmd1</property>
            </ExecutionCommand>
            <ExecutionCommand>
                <property name="Name">Cmd2</property>
            </ExecutionCommand>
        </ExecutionBlock>
    <ExecutionBlock>
        <property name="Name">Block2</property>
        <ExecutionCommand>
            <property name="Name">Cmd1</property>
        </ExecutionCommand>
        <ExecutionCommand>
            <property name="Name">Cmd2</property>
        </ExecutionCommand>
    </ExecutionBlock>
</ExecutionSequence>
```

I want all the commnd names with their respective parent name

seq  Block1  cmd1

seq  Block1  cmd2

seq  Block2  cmd1

seq  Block2  cmd2

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    e.c.value('(property[@name="Name"]/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Sequence,
    b.c.value('(property[@name="Name"]/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Block,
    c.c.value('(property[@name="Name"]/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Command
from @data.nodes('ExecutionSequence') as e(c)
    outer apply e.c.nodes('ExecutionBlock') as b(c)
    outer apply b.c.nodes('ExecutionCommand') as c(c)
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22016)</kbd>**